# "no routes match" when running automatically generated functional tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, nested-resources

I am trying to solve the following error:

```
ElementsControllerTest#test_should_get_create:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"elements"}
test/controllers/elements_controller_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:ElementsControllerTest>'
```

`Element` is a nested resource (child of Piece)

```
    resources :batiments do
      resources :pieces
    end

    resources :pieces, shallow: true do
      resources :elements
    end
```

**test/controllers/elements_controller.rb**

```
class ElementsController < ApplicationController
 #after_filter :load_piece

  def index
   @piece = Piece.find(params[:piece_id])
    @elements = @piece.elements.all
  end

  def new
    @piece = Piece.find(params[:piece_id])
    @element = @piece.elements.new
  end


 def create
   @piece = Piece.find(params[:piece_id])
   @element = @piece.elements.new(element_params)
   if @element.save
     flash[:notice] = "Elément créé!"
   else
     flash[:alert] = "Elément non créé!"
   end
   redirect_to piece_path(@piece)
 end

…

end
```

and my routes for Element:

```
            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action

     piece_elements GET    /pieces/:piece_id/elements(.:format)              elements#index
                    POST   /pieces/:piece_id/elements(.:format)              elements#create
  new_piece_element GET    /pieces/:piece_id/elements/new(.:format)          elements#new
       edit_element GET    /elements/:id/edit(.:format)                      elements#edit
            element GET    /elements/:id(.:format)                           elements#show
                    PATCH  /elements/:id(.:format)                           elements#update
                    PUT    /elements/:id(.:format)                           elements#update
                    DELETE /elements/:id(.:format)                           elements#destroy
             pieces GET    /pieces(.:format)                                 pieces#index
                    POST   /pieces(.:format)                                 pieces#create
          new_piece GET    /pieces/new(.:format)                             pieces#new
         edit_piece GET    /pieces/:id/edit(.:format)                        pieces#edit
              piece GET    /pieces/:id(.:format)                             pieces#show
                    PATCH  /pieces/:id(.:format)                             pieces#update
                    PUT    /pieces/:id(.:format)                             pieces#update
                    DELETE /pieces/:id(.:format)                             pieces#destroy
```

UPDATE: **elements_controller_test.rb** in /test

```
     require 'test_helper'

    class ElementsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
      test "should get create" do
        get :create
        assert_response :success
      end
    end
```

Comment: Please share `elements_controller_test.rb` in your question.

Comment: Thank you Kirti. It's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your test case as below:

```
  class ElementsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
      test "should get create" do
        post :create, element: {attrb1: "value", attrb2: "value"}, piece_id: id_of_existing_piece_record                    ## Post method
        assert_response :success
      end
    end
```

`create` is a `post` route not a `get` route. This is why you are getting error as `No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"elements"}`
Also, as `elements` is nested within `pieces` , you would have to pass an id of existing piece to your `post :create`  call.

`element: {attrb1: "value", attrb2: "value"}` is for the attributes that you would like to save in element record.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but this does not solve the error.
I add that Rails generated these unit-test, not me...

Comment: As elements is nested within pieces , you would have to pass an id of existing piece to your `post :create ` call.

Comment: @Dwidoo See my updated answer for better explanation

Comment: I tried your solution but got "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Piece with id=1" . 
I have checked in Rails Console with "Piece.find(1)" and it does exists. 
Have I missed something ? Is there a problem with my create method ?

Comment: Does it exist in `test` environment? Run `rails console -e test` and then do `Piece.find(1)`. Let me know.

Comment: It does not. Where should I create this instance of Piece ?

Comment: You need to create it in `test` db. You currently have it in `development` db BUT your tests would refer to `test` db and not `development` db.

Comment: OK I added the Piece in `test` db (checked in `test` console) and now I have the following Error: `Failure:
ElementsControllerTest#test_should_get_create [/Users/davidsultan/rails_projects/diag/test/controllers/elements_controller_test.rb:16]:
Expected response to be a <success>, but was <302>`

Comment: Thats because you are redirecting at the end of create action and `redirect_to` goes to 302 by default and you are checking it against response code `success` which is 200.